# Firefox Javascript div rotation not working, but does work in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, firefox, rotation, compatibility

`loadingSpinner2.style['-webkit-transform'] = "rotate(45deg)";`

This line doesn't seem to set the rotation of the loading spinner but in Safari and Chrome it does. How do I make it work in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just want to add to @Musa. `transform` is new CSS3 property, so the full code in CSS will look like

```
-moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* For Firefox<16.0 */
-ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* For IE9 only */
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* For Safari, Chrome, iOS */
-o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* For Opera<12.10 */
transform: rotate(45deg); /* For all other CSS3 compatible major browser */
```

so you have to use all of them in this order in your JS, but still it doesn't promise you full browser-support

EDIT As I understand from your coment you're interested in order of using them: usually the most modern property is the last to apply to override all old properties

Comment: as long as it supports the major browsers - Safari, Chrome, Firefox (what about IE 10?) its fine.

Comment: does i.e. 10 support the last one?

Comment: @DylanThepiguy check this: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d) it even shows prefixes

Comment: your code works in firefox. thanks. but the caniuse thing doesn't show many prefixes by the looks of it...

Comment: @DylanThepiguy yes, I've also noticed, that, for example, it doesn't present `-o-` prefix for Opera, but I hope it gives the main idea

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are using webkit prefixes (chrome and safari are build on webkit) so they wont work o non webkit browsers like firefox.
For firefox use the `-moz-` prefix

```
loadingSpinner2.style['-moz-transform'] = "rotate(45deg)";
```

For opera there is `-o-`

```
loadingSpinner2.style['-o-transform'] = "rotate(45deg)";
```

for IE (>=10) leave out the prefix.

---

```
.rot{
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg); /* For Firefox<16.0 */
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg); /* For IE9 only */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); /* For Safari, Chrome, iOS */
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg); /* For Opera<12.10 */
    transform: rotate(45deg); /* For all other CSS3 compatible major browser */
}
```

```
loadingSpinner2.classList.add('rot');
```

Comment: what about other browsers? and does that line of code work for all?

Comment: @DylanThepiguy you'll have to set each one just like in css.

Comment: so should i use a browser detection thing? or use several simultaneously

Comment: @DylanThepiguy rather than using inline styles you could use classes. Adding and removing them from elements to trigger styles.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean by this. Also that is javascript and it changes the rotation by 1 degree every 1/60 second.

Comment: @DylanThepiguy css classes as in `.rot{transform:rotate(45deg)}`

Comment: how can i set this in javascript?